# Backbone model attributes are nested twice after upgrading to backbone 1.3.3

Tags: backbone.js, backgrid

After upgrading my project to backbone 1.3.3 my attributes are nested inside another attributes parameter.

What I mean is that they appear in this.model.attributes.attributes rather than in this.model.attributes.

This seems to happen in instances of Marionette.CollectionView as well as Backgrid.Cell but not in other View instances. I put some debug statements inside the Backgrid Cell code and it seems that the model comes with this issue even when initializing it.

It doesn't seem that I am changing the model anywhere in my code after the upgrade nor did I before, is this a change inherent to backbone or backgrid?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that directly upgrading backbone was not the issue but instead the dependency to backbone-pageable. backbone-pageable has been deprecated and replaced for backbone.paginator which was the one causing the issue as my model was formatted differently. Parsing and reformatting the result of my pageable collection was the solution. Alternatively downgrading to backbone-pageable also solves the problem.